# Collections.emptyList() instead of null check?

Tags: java, collections, null, empty-list

If I have a rarely used collection in some class which may be instantiated many times, I may sometimes resort to the following "idiom" in order to save unnecessary object creations:

```
List<Object> list = null;

void add(Object object) {
    if (list == null)
        list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    list.add(object);
}

// somewhere else
if (list != null)
    for (Object object : list)
         ;
```

Now I was wondering if I couldn't eliminate those null checks using `Collections.emptyList()`, however then I would have to alter the if check in `add()` like so:

```
if (list == Collections.<Object>emptyList())
    list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Is there a better way to handle this other than just allocating a new empty collection every time?

**EDIT:** just to be clear, I *would like* to use Collections.emptyList(), but the above check in add() is really really ugly... I was wondering if there's a better way to do it or even a whole other way of handling this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> ***in order to save unnecessary object creations***

That's a really bad idea which will litter your code with `== null` checks and other handling of corner cases (and presumably end up in null pointer exceptions anyway)!

> ***Now I was wondering if I couldn't eliminate those null checks using `Collections.emptyList()`***

No, not really. `emptyList()` returns an empty list. You *could* do

```
if (list.equals(Collections.<Object>emptyList()))
```

but that will still throw a NullPointerException if `list == null`, so it's still not what you're after.

My recommendation: Always initialize the list to `new ArrayList<Object>`, or, if you for instance want to return an empty list from a method, use `Collections.emptyList()` instead. (This returns the same instance every time, so no unnecessary object creation there either.)

And then use `.isEmpty()` to check if a collection is empty or not.

Comment: I want to, but you can't add objects to Collections.emptyList(), hence the check in add()...

Comment: In those situations you should definitely go with `new ArrayList<Object>()` always.

Comment: @Philip then use `new ArrayList<Object>()` along with `.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Well, if I do initialize the list to emptyList() I can then check in add if it is == Collections.emptyList() and only then allocate a new mutable list. This eliminates both null checks and unnecessary object creations but the == Collections.emptyList() check in add() bothers me a lot :/

Comment: Uhm... that's true. It will cost you an extra `if`-statement in every single `add` and will be a greater concern when it comes to thread safety. Are you sure that this part is some form of bottle-neck in your application? Smells premature optimization to me.

Comment: It kind of is, I was just looking for some sort of best-of-both-worlds generalized "idiom" which I can always use, but I guess there is no such thing :)

Comment: Ah, well, then the question actually makes more sense. I believe the answer is no though.

Comment: I think you _do_ have a great generalized idiom, and it's 'new ArrayList()'.  It's going to be the rare _specialized_ situation in which that costs you so much memory it really matters.

Comment: @aioobe said `list.equals(Collections.<Object>emptyList())` could throw NullPointerException if `list == null`. Couldn't you do `Collections.<Object>emptyList().equals(list)` then?

Answer (score 24):

The suggested answers are absolutely correct, just small tip - in Java 8 you can use the new [Optional class](http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-10-06-java-8-removing-null-checks-with-optional/) to handle the case where the list instance is null, in a more functional approach.

For example, something like this:

```
public static List<String> addElement(List<String> list, String toAdd) {
       List<String> newList = Optional.ofNullable(list).orElse(new ArrayList<>());
       newList.add(toAdd);
       return newList;
}
```

Following a tip in the comments, it's better to replace `new ArrayList<>()` with `Collections.emptyList()` in order to prevent the creation of a new instance of an empty ArrayList

```
public static List<String> addElement(List<String> list, String toAdd) {
   List<String> newList = Optional.ofNullable(list).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
   newList.add(toAdd);
   return newList;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. One quick improvement would be to use the emptyList collection in order to prevent creating a new instance of an empty ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, good tip. I won't update the answer and keep it like that for future reference :)

Comment: How is creating an extra Optional object better than a null check?

Comment: ... ArrayList<>() with Collections.emptyList() in order to prevent the creation of a new instance of an empty ArrayList...

That's plain wrong. You ARE creating a list with `emptyList` as well. The only difference is immutability.

Answer (score 13):

There is an `emptyIfNull` method in `package org.apache.commons.collections4;`. It returns an empty list if the one provided is null.

```java
List<Object> list = CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(list);
```

Comment: minor addition - in some version they moved it into

org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I use for a helper method in some of my code. Really works nicely in reducing the ton of null checks I'd normally have to place before iterating over lists. If you want a list that wouldn't be immutable then you can return a new list object instead of Collections.emptyList

```
/**
 * Helper method to return an empty list if provided one is null.
 *
 * @param list the list
 * @return the provided list or an empty one if it was null
 */
private static <T> List<T> emptyIfNull(List<T> list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return list;
}
```

You then just use the helper method like so:

```
for (Object object : emptyIfNull(existingList)) { ... }
```

If the list object is null, then the helper method will return the static empty list and the contents of your loop will be skipped.  This is a nice way to avoid having to create null checks wrapping any list iterations.

I've made the internals of the list be of type Object just for the example, but you'd obviously change this to be whatever makes the most sense for your usage.

Answer (score 2):

emptyList() doesn't allocate an object each time.

I would create less of the object which contains the List so you can create the list every time.

What you can do is

```
private List<Object> list = Collections.emptyList();

private List<Object> listForWrite() {
    return list.isEmpty() ? list = new ArrayList<Object>() : list;
}


void add(Object object) {
    listForWrite().add(object);
}


// avoid creating an Iterator every time.
for (int i = 0, size = list.size(); i < size; i++) {
     ;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. Though now you're in for some thread-safety issues and synchronization overhead for every call to `list()` instead.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Now you might create new `ArrayLists` even though `list` already refers to a mutable list.

Comment: Yes, but then you would create a new ArrayList every time the list is empty (i.e. *not only* if it is indeed Collections.emptyList()), right?

Comment: If you are using ArrayList, you are going to have thread safety and synchronisation issues anyway. It only if the class needs to be thread safe and you are using a safe collection, its starts to matter.

Comment: @Philip K, That depends if you it is likely you will add entries and remove that all and add some more. Using a Iterator is likely to be far more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation on using optional as @Stas suggested, but also using the isEmpty immutable collection as originally requested in the question:

```
public static List<String> addElement(List<String> list, String toAdd) {
   List<String> newList = Optional.ofNullable(list).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
   newList.add(toAdd);
   return newList;
}
```

This approach is also the closest thing I can find to the nice ability in Javascript to use an empty array if the collection is null.

For example:

```
// no need to indent everything inside a null check of myObjects
for (MyObj myObj : Optional.ofNullable(myObjects).orElse(Collections.emptyList())){
    // do stuff with myObj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the list for iterations, you could just use: `for (Object object : list)` which wouldn't do anything for empty lists, i.e. not a single iteration.

Otherwise just check `list.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Not if he insists on letting `null` represent empty collections.

Comment: @aioobe You're right, but then using `Collections.emptyList()` wouldn't get you any advantage, would it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a utility class with static methods, like:

```
public class ListUtil {

/**
 * Checks if {@link List} is null or empty.
 *
 * @param <E> the generic type
 * @param list the list
 * @return true, if is null or empty
 */
public static <E> boolean isNullOrEmpty(List<E> list) {
    return list == null || list.size() == 0;
}

/**
 * Checks if {@link List} is not null and empty.
 *
 * @param <E> the generic type
 * @param list the list
 * @return true, if is not null and empty
 */
public static <E> boolean isNotNullAndEmpty(List<E> list) {
    return list != null && list.size() != 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Actually, apache commons collections already has such a utility class: `CollectionUtils`

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. I was not aware of it. :)

Comment: That's not what I was after, I don't want to replace == null with isNullOrEmpty(), I don't want *any* checks when I iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to follow this convention:

1. If the point of my methods is to return a Collection, the method never returns null. Null is ambiguous. Instead I return `Collection.emptyXXX()` or `ImmutableXXX.of()` if using Guava.
2. If I have an object which is maintaining an internal list as a member, instantiate it in the constructor. I try not to do lazy instantiation unless I can prove its a significant gain because lazy code, *in my opinion*, tends to be more difficult to debug when issues arise.

I really see immutable or unmodifiable empty collections being a part of a contract external to objects. If you are using the collection internally, I can only really see using immutable collections if you have a good reason (concurrency, consistency, immutability of the object)